# Blazor Server on IIS10 - only 4 concurrent connections

Tags: c#, iis, blazor

One of my customers suddenly reported that a local website I've made in Server-side Blazor only can have 4 concurrent connections. When the 5th connection is established, one of the other 4 is getting disconnected.
I Have looked through my configuration and can't see any sign of this. Connections is not limited in IIS configuration.

OS: Windows Server 2016

I have tried to debug at my local copy of the virtual machine, but here everything is working as expected.

Anyone who got a clue what I can look for?

Comment: Does the server have very low available memory?

Comment: I don't have this issue on my local IIS. 4 Connections limit should only happened on client OS like win 10. Could you post the error message that is returned from the disconnected request and what the status.sub-status code is? Did you see any exception in application event viewer?

Comment: Ok, so he reports that with 1 session the server CPU jumps to 53%. When he is closing the session, the CPU falls back to 2%. When I run the same code in my virtual machine, I can have 10 sessions with 8% of CPU usage.

Comment: I'm seeing some strange behaviour in my testsetup. When I run debugging from within VS, I can run 20+ sessions without any hickups and minimal load on the server (1-2% cpu and 241 mb of ram). But when I deploy to my virual machine with IIS10, I can only run 6 sessions and the 7th keeps spinning in the loading favicon (Chrome). Some of the elements on the page doesn't load on the 7th session.